# unable to animate from fragment to activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I am trying to animate fab button from fragment to activity in android. The code below works from activity to another activity but not from fragment to activity in android.How can I make it work?

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton fab;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
             i.putExtra("title",  "title");

                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), fab, "image");
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), i, options.toBundle());

    } }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had added 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in manifest file removing that makes it work.